# prevalence of UCS2 vs UCS4 python chars

Tags: python-2.x, compiler-flags, python-unicode

[builtin functions - `unichr`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#unichr) says

> The valid range for the argument depends how Python was configured – it may be either UCS2 [0..0xFFFF] or UCS4 [0..0x10FFFF]

and

[builtin functions - `ord`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#ord) says

> If a unicode argument is given and Python was built with UCS2 Unicode, then the character’s code point must be in the range [0..65535] inclusive; otherwise the string length is two, and a TypeError will be raised.

Are there any stats on how widely used the two definitions of *code-unit* are in production python interpreters?

Any idea how prevalent python scripts are that use something like `#!/usr/bin/env python` and which run with different code-unit definitions based on the environment of the user running it?

---

Background:

I'm wondering how much work to put into making a parser generator backend for python 2.x produce a single library that works for both configurations given that [Python 3 tightened this](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#chr).

Specifically, am I likely bloating the generated code bundle unnecessarily by doing

```
# Module my_generated_parser
try
  unichr(0x10000)
except ValueError:
  from my_generated_parser_ucs2 import *
else:
  from my_generated_parser_ucs4 import *
```

and including two generated parsers by default?